# which is the usual definition of Argument?

Tags: complex-analysis, definition

Let $z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$

Then, there exists a unique $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$ and $\phi\in(-\pi,\pi]$ such that $z=|z|e^{i\theta}=|z|e^{i\phi}$.

Between $\phi$ and $\theta$, which is the usual definition of $Arg(z)$?

**I know** that these two are basically the same for the purpose of its use, but i'm hesitating to take which to choose as my definition of $Arg(z)$..

Comment: The first sentence is false as stated. You should mention that $z \neq 0$.

Comment: @Dan You are right. I will edit it

Comment: As long as you state which you are using, either would be fine to use as a definition.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, the $\theta$ version is used, i.e. $[0, 2\pi)$. However, in the case of functions that are locally holomorphic, but cannot be taken to be holomorphic in the whole of $\Bbb C$ (e.g. $\ln z$), we have to define a *branch cut*, and that is usually taken to be the negative real axis, and we are thus implicitly choosing to use arguments in the range $[-\pi, \pi)$.

Comment: What about the converse? Is there a case which works for arguments in $[0,2\pi)$ but doesn't for arguments in $(-\pi,\pi]$?